# Contacts matching query does not exist in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, postman

I am trying to update Contact model fields while creating the new fields of UpdateInfo model and add them to the existing model.

But I am getting this error

**contacts.models.Contacts.DoesNotExist: Contacts matching query does not exist.**

I know the contact object with the id 19 exists because I can see it when I try the get contacts API.

I am sending data like this.

[image]

My models:

```
class Contacts(models.Model):
   full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
   .........

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Potential Clients'



class UpdateInfo(models.Model):
    contacts = models.ForeignKey(Contacts,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='update_info')
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    modified_by = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return f"Last modified by {self.modified_by} at {self.updated_at}"
```

My views:

```
class EditContactView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Contacts.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContactsUpdateSeializer
```

My serializers:

```
class UpdateInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    contacts= serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = UpdateInfo
        fields = ['id','contacts','updated_at','modified_by']


class ContactsUpdateSeializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    update_info = UpdateInfoSerializer(many=True)
    id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Contacts
        fields = ['id', 'full_name', 'lead_source', 'email', 'phone', 'contact_owner',
                  'contact_status', 'company_name', 'job_position', 'tasks',
                  'notes', 'email_list', 'created_by', 'created_at', 'update_info']


    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        update_data = validated_data.pop('update_info')
        id = validated_data.get('id')
        contacts = Contacts.objects.get(id=id)
        #contacts.save()

        #contact_only_update_logic
        instance.full_name = validated_data.get('full_name')
        instance.lead_source = validated_data.get('lead_source')
        instance.email = validated_data.get('email')
        instance.phone = validated_data.get('phone')
        instance.contact_owner = validated_data.get('contact_owner')
        instance.contact_status = validated_data.get('contact_status')
        instance.company_name = validated_data.get('company_name')
        instance.job_position = validated_data.get('job_position')
        instance.tasks = validated_data.get('tasks')
        instance.notes = validated_data.get('notes')
        instance.email_list = validated_data.get('email_list')
        instance.save()

        #add_update_info_logic

        for update_data in update_data:
            abc = UpdateInfo.objects.create(contacts=contacts,**update_data)
            instance.update_info.add(abc)

        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your serializer

```
class ContactsUpdateSeializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    update_info = UpdateInfoSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Contacts
        fields = ['id', 'full_name', 'lead_source', 'email', 'phone', 'contact_owner',
                  'contact_status', 'company_name', 'job_position', 'tasks',
                  'notes', 'email_list', 'created_by', 'created_at', 'update_info']


    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        update_data = validated_data.pop('update_info')
        instance = super(ContactsUpdateSeializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)
        
        for update_datum in update_data:
            abc = UpdateInfo.objects.create(contacts=instance,**update_datum)
            
        return instance
```

`PrimaryKeyRelatedField` is used for foreign key purpose and there we have to define queryset also.

Don't need to add the updateinfo in contact, it is already done throgh django.

Moreover, it would be better if you use `bulk_create` instead of running `save` each time if you there is no signals exists for that.

You can do it as:-

```
UpdateInfo.objects.bulk_create([UpdateInfo(contacts=instance,**update_datum) for update_datum in update_data])
```

Comment: Moreover if you like make id as readonly field as you defined in your Serializer, so just use attribute read_only_fields = ("id",)

Comment: Ok I am new to this. Can you please tell me at which conditon do we have to use super.update??  Also second question, isnt instance already there, why do we have to get it using super.update?? As you can see, I am using instance.full_name =....,

Comment: ModelSerializer update already save your model related changes but if you need extra work then you can add afterward as I added there for create updateinfo.